# Detect Firefox plugins?

Tags: php, javascript, firefox

Is there any method to detect Firefox plugins? I remember it was possible through the local path to the plugin icon, but I believe that was covered already, unfortunately.

Does anybody know if there is any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP (server-side) does not have any knowledge about client-side including plugins unless they (plugins) add some information in headers sent by browser.

You can use javascript. But in scenario where user disables javascript you still won't be able to get installed plugins.

[Here](http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins/)'s interesting article about plugin detection with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/

i am no way affiliated with webdevwonders.com

=)